# HTML, href inside <a> tag is not working

Tags: html

I have created a link to YouTube using  tag in HTML, but it doesn't work when I click on the text. Here is the code:

```
<div>
   <p>Source to <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
   <span style="color:red">Youtube</span></a>.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help for the answers

Comment: your code has an error, the attribute is `href` not `herf`

Comment: herf are you sure? I think the attribute is called href

Comment: it's `href`, which stands for "Hypertext REFerence"

Answer (score 1):

It must be `href` not “herf”. Just a normal syntax error or typo.

Comment: Thanks I should have noticed that

Answer (score 0):

Find the difference :D

```html
<a herf="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://www.youtube.com)
to view my YouTube video.

```
Click <a href="http://www.youtube.com">here</a>to view my YouTube video.
```

This will helpful to you

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp